# Whats the best way to 'make' a web developer

Tags: software-development

We have a team of developers and everyone has graduate degree,

but they are just degrees... no practical experience, they just studied it so that they can get a job.

Before, we used to teach them all required languages (PHP, HTML, CSS, Mysql etc)

But now we think they need some common sense

ex: when we say make a signup form, they should know atleast that it should contains email,password, confirm password, submit button.

It may look silly to you but some are making forms without password.

So i think we need to teach them some more things (common sense?)

Previously i used to tell them to watch all famous websites and how they are building each and every page but that doesn't seem to work much.

How can 'make' them better programmers.

NOTE: I Doubt mods may close this as its too general but it has become a big headache for us
and clients thinking of us as dumb, just because some devs doing silly things.

Comment: Hey cnu, the short answer is hire smart people. Also, you might check out [Programmers SE's help center](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to see if this is on-topic there. This site is for questions about the field of project management.

Answer (score 3):

First, there is no such thing as common sense.  Second, identify what knowledge, skills, and abilities you need for the work you have.  Third, identify the gaps between what you need and what you have with your hired employees.  Fourth, train to close those gaps.

No magic formula.  Work performance is based on what people know, how they apply what they know, and how good they get through practice.

If you don't have the time or capability to train in a competent way, then hire replacements.  This means you need to research a bit on performance predictors.  Here's a hint: degrees and certificates are of low validity as it relates to predicting performance.

Comment: yes,
I reaally dont believe in degrees at all,
they are just a medium to filter candidates.
And we are not hiring freshers, mostly ppl with 1 year experience and if they don't learn we need a password field for signup... how can we help them and get works done

Comment: -1 if I could, This is just incorrect.  Cognitive ability highly correlates with work performance, and high education levels correlate with high cognitive ability, so education level, difficulty, and pedigree are indeed good predictors of performance.  See http://psycnet.apa.org/journals/psp/86/1/148/

Comment: Start with Hunter and Hunter. They reference others. This is about validity as predictors. School is important, but there are many who can get through school but can't perform. They lower the validity.

Comment: @daaxix I have to agree with David on this. I'm quite careful in the interviewing process and I general end up hiring quite talented people. As I see how people do in the real world, many top-tier devs have no undergraduate degree (some no university at all). In fact, I would not give any 'points' in the hiring process for having a degree...because my real-world experience as a PM seeing no correlation between degrees and on-the-job performance. I will, however, read that link. :-)

Comment: I agree with your answer but _"Fourth, train to close those gaps"_ should include the option to hire to close those gaps.

Comment: @earthling, +1, I agree!